# The compiler failed with error code -1073741819

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors

We are getting below error. And it requires server restart every time.

```
The compiler failed with error code -1073741819.
```

Also, ASP.Net is working fine - ONLY ASP.Net MVC applications are not working..

Any idea?

Comment: -1073741819 = 0xc0000005 = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. When you say compiler, is this IIS compiling ASP.NET pages on first access? Is it running as an app pool user with permission to write to the "Temporary ASP.NET files" folder under c:\windows\microsoft.net\Framework(64)\version? If it's not there, can you e.g. use [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to watch for the actual failure and see what it was trying to do.

Comment: I tried either ways as you suggested - Given full required rights to user accounts and given to IIS pool but still not working.

Comment: Did u solved this Error?

Comment: Yes, only way I found is restart. Bug in windows IIS.

Answer (score 6):

My error code was `-5324627661` working Visual Studio 2015 and IIS Express, happend after editing site.css while the project was debugging and didn't go away with just (windows) restart.

After restart I deleted the project files (.dll, .config, .pdb) from bin and rebuilt the project. That solved the error.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I wasn't able to completely clean my bin folder. My process 'VBCSCompiler.exe' caused the issue. I had to kill it with the task manager then I was able to rebuild correctly.

Comment: Thnks, it fixed problem for me too

Answer (score 3):

Deleting bin and obj folders and recompiling the solution solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error,I was about to pull my hairs over this issue, tried all the approaches mentioned in Stackoverflow and other sources none of them worked. Finally I figured that out myself,the **problem** was from my **web.config file**. I'd published my local web.config on server.

I copied another server web.config file from another identical server (which was working well) and problem solved and life became beautiful again!

**I can say for sure that there is some thing wrong with your web.config file**

Answer (score 0):

My Error Code was `532462766` .
Just delete all the files in the bin folder and a Rebuild will fix your problem.