# Adding DLL in Visual Studio 2013 causes Compiler Error -107374181 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I am trying to add a reference to a dll, but when I compile the project I get:

> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741819.

I have tried:

- changing the security permissions on the dll to allow full control
- running visual studio as administrator.

I have added the dll with copylocal = false, but it fails at runtime with a "file not found" error.

I created a separate project with the same framework version (4.5) and was able to add the dll without any trouble, but unfortunately I need to add it to the existing legacy project.

The legacy project source files are in GitHub, but the bin folder where I am adding the DLL to is not in Github.

Comment: Hmm, no, that is 0xC0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.  Crashing the compiler with such a very nasty exception is pretty unusual.  You need to try this on another machine.  Technically it could be caused by the owner of this DLL not wanting you to use it without a proper usage license.  Use a telephone.

Comment: I thought it was ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED after reading this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609035/the-compiler-failed-with-error-code-1073741819

Comment: The dll has a license file, which I have already included in the project. As noted in the OP I created a separate project which worked. This was on the same machine.